# Room Local Unit Test - Query PagedList from DataSource.Factory

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-testing, junit5

## Issue

#### Expected

Using a JUnit 5 local unit test, run a Room database `@Insert` and `Query` within a `TestCoroutineDispatcher()`.

#### Observed

The Room database `@Insert` and `@Query` is executed within `TestCoroutineDispatcher().runBlockingTest`, causing the error below. The database calls will work if the threading is explicitly defined with the non-test dispatcher, `Dispatchers.IO`.

Error log:

> Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.

## Implement

**1. Add libraries**

- JUnit 5: [Setup](https://github.com/mannodermaus/android-junit5#setup)
- Robolectric: [Getting Started](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/)
- AndroidX: Set up project for AndroidX Test > [List of AndroidX Test dependencies](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project#gradle-dependencies)
- Kotlin coroutines: [Using in your project](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test#using-in-your-project)

*build.gradle (SomeProjectName)*

```
dependencies {
    ...
    // JUnit 5
    classpath("de.mannodermaus.gradle.plugins:android-junit5:X.X.X")
}
```

*build.gradle (:someModuleName)*

```
apply plugin: "de.mannodermaus.android-junit5"

// JUnit 5
testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:X.X.X"
testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:X.X.X"

// Robolectric
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:X.X.X"
testImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:X.X.X"

testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:X.X.X"
```

**2. Create test**

a. Set test Dispatcher and LiveData executor.

b. Create a test database: [Test and debug your database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/testing-db).

c. Ensure the test database executes on the same Dispatcher as the unit test: [Testing AndroidX Room + Kotlin Coroutines](https://medium.com/@eyalg/testing-androidx-room-kotlin-coroutines-2d1faa3e674f) - [@Eyal Guthmann](http://twitter.com/@EyalGuthmann)

d. Run the database `@Insert` and `@Query` within `TestCoroutineDispatcher().runBlockingTest`.

*SomeTest.kt*

```kotlin
import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@Config(maxSdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.P, minSdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class SomeTest {

    private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    @Test
    fun someTest() = testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {

        // Test setup, moved to test extension in production. Also, cleanup methods not included here for simplicity.

        // Set Coroutine Dispatcher.
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
        // Set LiveData Executor.
        ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance().setDelegate(object : TaskExecutor() {
            override fun executeOnDiskIO(runnable: Runnable) = runnable.run()
            override fun postToMainThread(runnable: Runnable) = runnable.run()
            override fun isMainThread(): Boolean = true
        })
        val appContext = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
        // Room database setup
        db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(appContext, SomeDatabase::class.java)
            .setTransactionExecutor(testDispatcher.asExecutor())
            .setQueryExecutor(testDispatcher.asExecutor())
            .build()
        dao = db.someDao()

        // Insert into database.
        dao.insertData(mockDataList)
        // Query database.
        val someQuery = dao.queryData().toLiveData(PAGE_SIZE).asFlow()
        someQuery.collect {
            // TODO: Test something here.
        }

        // TODO: Make test assertions.
        ...
}
```

*SomeDao.kt*

```kotlin
@Dao
interface SomeDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertData(data: List<SomeData>)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM someDataTable")
    fun queryData(): DataSource.Factory<Int, SomeData>
}
```

## Attempted solutions

### 1. Add `suspend` modifier to *SomeDao.kt*'s `queryData` function.

After adding `suspend`, the methods that subsequently call `queryData` must either implement `suspend` as well or be launched using `launch`, from a coroutine, as shown below.

This results in an error from the compiler.

> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (androidx.paging.DataSource.Factory<{SomeDataClassPathHere}>).

*SomeDao.kt*

```kotlin
@Dao
interface SomeDao {
    ...
    @Query("SELECT * FROM someDataTable")
    suspend fun queryData(): DataSource.Factory<Int, SomeData>
}
```

*SomeRepo.kt*

```kotlin
suspend fun getInitialData(pagedListBoundaryCallback: PagedList.BoundaryCallback<SomeData>) = flow {
        emit(Resource.loading(null))
        try {
            dao.insertData(getDataRequest(...))
            someDataQuery(pagedListBoundaryCallback).collect {
                emit(Resource.success(it))
            }
        } catch (error: Exception) {
            someDataQuery(pagedListBoundaryCallback).collect {
                emit(Resource.error(error.localizedMessage!!, it))
            }
        }
    }
```

*SomeViewModel.kt*

```kotlin
private suspend fun loadNetwork(toRetry: Boolean) {
    repository.getInitialData(pagedListBoundaryCallback(toRetry)).onEach {
            when (it.status) {
                LOADING -> _viewState.value = ...
                SUCCESS -> _viewState.value = ...
                ERROR -> _viewState.value = ...
            }
    }.flowOn(coroutineDispatcherProvider.io()).launchIn(coroutineScope)
}

fun bindIntents(view: FeedView) {
        view.loadNetworkIntent().onEach {
            coroutineScope.launch(coroutineDispatcherProvider.io()) {
                loadNetwork(it.toRetry)
            }
        }.launchIn(coroutineScope)
    }

 private fun pagedListBoundaryCallback(toRetry: Boolean) =
        object : PagedList.BoundaryCallback<SomeData>() {
            override fun onZeroItemsLoaded() {
                super.onZeroItemsLoaded()
                if (toRetry) {
                    coroutineScope.launch(coroutineDispatcherProvider.io()) {
                        loadNetwork(false)
                    }
                }
            }
```

### 2. Run the test with `TestCoroutineScope`.

*SomeTest.kt*

```kotlin
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@Config(maxSdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.P, minSdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class SomeTest {
    private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
    private val testScope = TestCoroutineScope(testDispatcher)


    @Test
    fun someTest() = testScope.runBlockingTest {
        ... 
    }
```

### 3. Run the test with `runBlockingTest`.

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun someTest() = runBlockingTest {
        ... 
    }
```

### 4. Launch the Room calls using TestCoroutineScope on TestCoroutineDispatcher.

This doesn't cause a main thread error. However, the Room calls do not work with this method.

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun topCafesTest() = testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
        testScope.launch(testDispatcher) {
            dao.insertCafes(mockCafesList)
            val cafesQuery = dao.queryCafes().toLiveData(PAGE_SIZE).asFlow()
            cafesQuery.collect {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

## Full error log

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
>
> at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:267)
>       at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:351)
>       at app.topcafes.feed.database.FeedDao_Impl$2.call(FeedDao_Impl.java:91)
>       at app.topcafes.feed.database.FeedDao_Impl$2.call(FeedDao_Impl.java:88)
>       at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion$execute$2.invokeSuspend(CoroutinesRoom.kt:54)
>       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
>       at androidx.room.TransactionExecutor$1.run(TransactionExecutor.java:45)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineDispatcher.dispatch(TestCoroutineDispatcher.kt:50)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatcherExecutor.execute(Executors.kt:62)
>       at androidx.room.TransactionExecutor.scheduleNext(TransactionExecutor.java:59)
>       at androidx.room.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:52)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.ExecutorCoroutineDispatcherBase.dispatch(Executors.kt:82)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:288)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:26)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:166)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source)
>       at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion.execute(CoroutinesRoom.kt:53)
>       at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom.execute(CoroutinesRoom.kt)
>       at app.topcafes.feed.database.FeedDao_Impl.insertCafes(FeedDao_Impl.java:88)
>       at app.topcafes.FeedTest$topCafesTest$1.invokeSuspend(FeedTest.kt:76)
>       at app.topcafes.FeedTest$topCafesTest$1.invoke(FeedTest.kt)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt$runBlockingTest$deferred$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:50)
>       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineDispatcher.dispatch(TestCoroutineDispatcher.kt:50)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:288)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:26)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:109)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:158)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.async(Builders.common.kt:91)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.async(Unknown Source)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.async$default(Builders.common.kt:84)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.async$default(Unknown Source)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:49)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:80)
>       at app.topcafes.FeedTest.topCafesTest(FeedTest.kt:70)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:546)
>       at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:252)
>       at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Can you include your `Dao` and your `queryData()` method? Room's support for `suspend insert()` methods already switch off of the main thread.

Comment: I've updated the code sample above to include the Dao. Also, I've attempted to refactor `queryData` to implement `suspend`. The compiler throws  _error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (androidx.paging.DataSource.Factory<{SomeDataClassPathHere}>)._ I've made all of the cascading `queryData` calls either `suspend` functions as well or launched the functions from new `launch` calls as shown above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Run Room `@Insert` and `@Query` on `Dispatchers.IO`

*SomeTest.kt*

```kotlin
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@Config(maxSdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.P, minSdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class SomeTest {

    private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
    private val testScope = TestCoroutineScope(testDispatcher)

    @Test
    fun someTest() = testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
        // Same Dispatcher, LiveData, and Room setup used as defined in the question above.

        testScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // Insert into database.
            dao.insertData(mockDataList)
            // Query database.
            val someQuery = dao.queryData().toLiveData(PAGE_SIZE).asFlow()
            someQuery.collect {
                // TODO: Test something here.
            }
        }

        // TODO: Make test assertions.
        ...
}
```